# Creating a list with nested dictionaries in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, python-3.5, openpyxl

I want to loop through all rows in my Excel sheet and store the value of each row (starting at row 2) in individual dictionaries within 1 big list.

I have a simple list of items in an Excel spanning from Column A - Column D:

```
Fruit:  Quantity:   Color:  Cost
Apple   5           Red     0.6
Banana  6           Yellow  0.4
Orange  4           Orange  0.3
Kiwi    2           Green   0.1
```

I want the very first result to look like:

```
[{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Quantity': 5, 'Color': 'Red', 'Cost': 0.6}]
```

Here's how my code looks at the moment:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('fruit.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    fruit = sheet['A' + str(row)].value
    quantity = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    color = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    cost = sheet['D' + str(row)].value

    allFruits = [{'Fruit': fruit,
                'Quantity': quantity,
                'Color': color,
                'Cost': cost}]

print(allFruits)
```

When I run the code, the result prints only the very last active row in the sheet:

```
[{'Fruit': 'Kiwi', 'Quantity': 2, 'Color': 'Green', 'Cost': 0.1}]
```

I want this format for **ALL** the rows, not just the final row. I don't understand why the code is skipping all of the rows in between and just printing the final row. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign to `allFruits` inside your loop you overwrite it on each iteration.

Instead define the `allFruits` list outside of your loop and call `allFruits.append()` inside the loop to add each fruit dictionary.

```
allFruits = []

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    fruit = sheet['A' + str(row)].value
    quantity = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    color = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    cost = sheet['D' + str(row)].value

    allFruits.append({'Fruit': fruit,
                'Quantity': quantity,
                'Color': color,
                'Cost': cost})
```

You could also shorten your code up by doing:

```
allFruits = []
key_col = [('Fruit', 'A'), ('Quantity', 'B'), ('Color', 'C'), ('Cost', 'D')]

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    allFruits.append({key:sheet[col+str(row)].value for (key, col) in key_col})
```